# Nginx redirect 301 the entire content of the folder to a subdomain

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx

I'm using Wordpress and Nginx and I created a sub domain to host all the images

I already updated the database to define all the old url, eg; https://exemple.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/image_exemple.jpg to https://static.exemple.com/2015/06/image_exemple.jpg which works good, I can now access to the media thought this subdomain

The sub domain point to the same folder as Wordpress have by default for the medias **/wp-content/uploads/**

Now I'm trying to redirect the entire folder with a permanent redirect to my sub domain

```
location = /wp-content/uploads/ {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://static.exemple.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Its seems to work, when I do  `curl -I https://static.exemple.com/` to see the header response; it tell me **HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently** and the same if I do `curl -I https://exemple.com/wp-content/uploads`

But when I do for exemple **curl -I https://exemple.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/image.jpg** and https://static.exemple.com/2015/06/image.jpg both reponse is **HTTP/1.1 200 OK**

It seems to works but but it does mean that the redirect 301 works for the entire content of the folder.. For informations the folder **uploads/** have many sub folder.

I tried with

```
location = /wp-content/uploads/ { 
    return 301 https://static/exemple.com/$request_uri;
}
```

which response the same...
Maybe I did something wrong ..
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Ok I resolved the issue. I post it for who want to know how I did it.

The solution, simply put this line in your server block, not in some location.

```
rewrite ^(/wp-content/uploads)(.*)$ https://static.exemple.com$2 permanent;
```

now test the request with this command

```
curl -I https://exemple.com/2015/06/logo.jpg
```

You should see as answer **HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently**

and

**Location: https://static.exemple.com/2015/06/logo.jpg**

Anyways you can do it with wget or another tools !

wget -d URL